# Hackers on GFWL

Tags: dark-souls, cheats, games-for-windows-live

I've met a couple of hackers with infinite health on Dark Souls PC, and filed complaints with Games for Windows Live. Is this effective at all? How and when are players sanctioned?

Also, is there a known bug where someone's healthbar doesn't deplete in PvP?

Comment: Considering GFWL is being shut down completely, I don't think they're doing anything to the reports anymore, but this is pure speculation. I can tell you that there's no such bug, though.

Comment: @3ventic You are probably right, I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2):

Players are not sanctioned for cheating in Dark Souls PC due to the lack of support for GFWL (it being shut-down)

Players are however sanctioned on PSN and Xbox Live (not much use to you but it's relevant to the question)

There is no known bug which would cause a player's health bar not to deplete in PvP.

Answer (score 0):

Going to answer this as gwfl is NO LONGER being shut down. Reports can and will get people banned, though at a frustratingly low rate. It's also (sadly) a pretty common cheat to either constantly set your health to max or set your resistances to max.

Comment: Do you have source for this?